# How does Twitter send websockets to it's clients

Tags: javascript, python, twitter, websocket, socket.io

There are millions of tweets and millions of active users in the Twitter. When a tweet gets like or retweet,how do they send live updates(websockets) of every tweet to its clients?

I think they wouldn't send live updates(websockets) of each tweet to every active user, that would result in (no of active tweets)X(no of active users)=(millions)X(millions)>10^12 live updates in each minute, each user would get millions of updates(of all the tweets) in each minute.

I think the live update of a particular tweet would only be received by the users who are watching that particular tweet.If this assumption is correct,then please tell me, **how do they filter clients who are watching a particular tweet and send live updates of that tweet only to those filtered clients?**

I was just watching a tweet in the Twitter, I was surprised to see live updates in likes and retweets of that tweet.I haven't seen any social media(like Instagram) giving live updates for every single post of it.   I want to implement this method in my social media website.What I had concluded might or might not be correct, but I would request you to explain me, how does Twitter send live updates of every single tweet only to those particular users who are watching it.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, ONE device has ONE socket connection, to Twitter's cloud.

That ONE socket connection, receives ALL information from Twitter's cloud

- new tweets
- new likes
- new retweets
- everything else

all information comes on the ONE socket.

The cloud "figures out" what to send to who.

Is this what you were asking? Hope it clears it up.

The amazing thing is that twitter's cloud can connect to perhaps 100 ? million devices at the same time.  (This is an amazing, major engineering achievement which requires an incredible amount of hardware, money and engineers.)

---

BTW if you're trying to implement something like this for an experiment or client. These days it is inconceivable you'd try to write the server side to achiever this, from scratch.  Services exist, which do exactly this - example pusher.com, pubnub.com and so on.

(Indeed, these realtime infrastructure services, are, the basic technology of our era - everything runs on them.)

---

Here's a glance at the mind-boggling effort involved in Twitter's cloud: https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/infrastructure/2017/the-infrastructure-behind-twitter-scale.html

Comment: No,I'm not making for a startup,  I'm just making a social media website to learn web development,  I'm thinking to make it as best as I can for the users. After seeing twitter, I thought why couldn't I learn from it

Comment: @ram , that's great!  Please enjoy.  You'll need to start by making some demo projects with Pusher and PubNub.  It will only take a day or two.  Check out the amazing PubNub demos: https://www.pubnub.com/developers/demos/team-chat/  Services like Pusher work perfectly with the web, and apps too.

Comment: i don't want to take APIs from them,I'm trying to build everything like chat, group chat, notification, geo-location,etc by myself

Comment: Enjoy.  You realize you'll be building a server to do that?  Making the web page is trivial.

Comment: yes, i had done most of the things what I need. I'm assuming some problems that might occur when traffic increases, sending live updates to some particular users is a solution im looking for in heavy traffic

Comment: @ram I would recommend using  a Redis instance to subscribe and publish updates by named "channels". This is a very common approach. I authored [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) for real-time applications running Ruby and [facil.io](http://facil.io) for real-time apps using C, but you can use Redis directly and figure it out from there.

Comment: Can anyone guess-timate any advantages as to why twitter uses web sockets for the feed / notifications over SSE?

SSE "seems" like it would be good here since twitter is just pushing data to the client

Comment: @fattie - do you have any links or articles on twitters usage of web sockets for all the stuff you mentioned? Would love to dig in more. Frankly, our team has been having a hell of a time using server sent events for all the stuff you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Realtime communication or what you refer to as 'live updates' is all a play of various low-level networking protocols. Here's a bit of background on the protocols in general just so you know what you are working with:

A regular REST API uses the HTTP as the underlying protocol for communication, which follows the request and response paradigm, meaning the communication involves the client requesting some data or resource from a server, and the server responding back to that client. This is what you usually see in a regular website that isn't really live but shows or does something following a button click or similar trigger from the user.

However, HTTP is a stateless protocol, so every request-response cycle will end up having to repeat the header and metadata information. This incurs additional latency in case of frequently repeated request-response cycles.

[image: HTTP]

---

With [WebSockets](https://www.ably.io/concepts/websockets), although the communication still starts off as an initial HTTP handshake, it is further upgrades to follow the WebSockets protocol (i.e. if both the server and the client are compliant with the protocol as not all entities support the WebSockets protocol).

Now with WebSockets, it is possible to establish a full-duplex and persistent connection between the client and a server. This means that unlike a request and a response, the connection stays open for as long as the application is running (i.e. it’s persistent), and since it is full-duplex, two-way simultaneous communication is possible. Now the server is capable of initiating communication and 'push' some data to the client when new data (that the client is interested in) becomes available.

[image: WebSockets]

The WebSockets protocol is stateful and allows you to implement the Publish-Subscribe (or Pub/Sub) messaging pattern which is the primary concept used in the real-time technologies where you are able to get new updates in the form of server push without the client having to request (refresh the page) repeatedly. Examples of such applications other than Twitter are Uber-like vehicle location tracking, Push Notifications, Stock market prices updating in real-time, chat, multiplayer games, live online collaboration tools, etc.

You can check out a deep dive article on [WebSockets](https://www.ably.io/concepts/websockets) which explains the history of this protocol, how it came into being, what it’s used for and how you can implement it yourself.

---

Another interesting one is SSE or [Server-Sent Events](https://www.ably.io/concepts/server-sent-events) which is a subscribe-only version of WebSockets and restricted to the web platform. You can use SSE to receive real-time push updates from servers, but this would be unidirectional as you can only receive updates via SSE and not really publish anything. Here's a video where I explain this in much more detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4ni7GsiIbs

---

You can implement these various protocols as required from scratch or use a distributed messaging service like [Ably](https://www.ably.io) which not only provides the messaging infrastructure of these protocols but also offers other add-ons such as scalability, reliability, message ordering, protocol interoperability, etc, out of the box, which is essential for a production-level app.

Full disclaimer: I'm a Dev Advocate for Ably but I hope the info in my answer is useful to you nevertheless.